# Sparql Querty to DBpedia endpoint

Tags: sparql, geospatial, rdf, ontology, linked-data

I am new to SPARQL, and I need to write Sparql query to retrieve all the entities and links that DBpedia use from the Ordnance Survey ontologies.
In words, I need to find out,  how DBpedia is linked to Ordnance ontologies and how DBpedia  incorporates with it in terms of Geospatial data ?. Also, what kind of data dose the DBpedia use from ordnance survey ?

Comment: what? What are "Ordnance Survey ontologies"? Note, DBpedia does contains more or less just the Wikipedia infobox data. I'm not sure what you expect to get from DBpedia? Do you have a concrete example? I mean, for basically any Wikipedia page you can check their corresponding DBpedia entity to see which data of the Wikipedia is contained. So, is there anything in Wikipedia for you?

Comment: Recap: Dbpedia is more or less Wikipedia, a list of possible mappings to external datasets you can find here: http://wikidata.dbpedia.org/services-resources/interlinking

Comment: Thank you very much, Ordnance Survey is the national mapping agency of Great Britain. it provides Geo-spatial linked datasets, and assumes to be linked to all the clould linked datasets E.g. DBpedia, I need to know how Dbpedia is linked to Ordnance survey data? and what type of links used to connect both dataests as well as they inforamtion that Dbpedia use from Ordnance survey.

Comment: then you should ask how your dataset is linked to DBpedia, not vice versa - the direction matters. Still, I don't know which dataset exactly you are referring to, where is the link to the RDF data, where is the link to the SPARQL endpoint? If you mean this dataset https://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/datasets/os-linked-data , I cannot see links to DBpedia. Do you have a documentation where it was mentioned they provide links to DBpedia?

Comment: Thank you very much for you reply, yes, I mean the data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/datasets/os-linked-data  dataset that you have mentioned; however, I am not quite sure if whether they are linked or not, but I so in some literature examples of linking to DBpedia, I don't know if such links exist or just was an example.

Comment: Another question in the same context please, I know that Genomes dataset is linked to Ordnance suvery data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/datasets/os-linked-data  how I can specify what type of information are linked and used by Geonames from OS dataset.

Comment: Geonames is not linked to OS dataset - or where do you have those links? Also, the direction matters. Maybe OS is linked to Geonames, but not vice versa afaik. Can you share the reference where it is mentioned that Geonames is linked to OS? Also, the whole description of what is contained in OS is here: https://data.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/datasets/os-linked-data/about

Comment: Here is the link, shows that Geonames is linked to the OS https://www.geonames.org/datasources/ , Number 160 of the list you find Ordnance survey, also this link http://geovocab.org/mappings/  indicates that Geonames uses the Relationship ontology authored by OS. The Thing that I need I now to know exactly what links goes from OS to Geonames and Visa-versa and what type of information they use.